# How to cancel Push Notification Default Dialog in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, dialog

When the app is in `Foreground` state, I am seeing `dialog` box with notification title and body. I do not want to show this `dialog` box. Instead I want to use my own `dialog` box. I am pretty new to `Push Notification` feature so sorry if this is silly question. I have attached the sample image for the `dialog` box that I am getting right now.
[image]

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Cons.INTENT_FILTER);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // some custom data in bundle which I need.
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to handle notification

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};
```

I am also registering and unregistering `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Cons.INTENT_FILTER));

unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to register/unregister receiver

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Cons.INTENT_FILTER);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter)
// then unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Comment: Please see my updated code. I am doing that already in my code.